# Alterar se item aparece ou não em <p:Datatable>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Bom dia. Estou com a seguinte datatable:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês poderiam me dar uma luz de como eu poderia fazer pra esse Expansion aparecer apenas para as duas primeiras linhas? As demais não tem detalhamentos para aparecerem na expansão.

Pensei em utilizar o `rendered` se a linha for maior que 2 (ou 1, não sei se a contagem do datatable começa de 0 ou 1). O que acham? Se julgam uma boa ideia, sabem como eu posso retornar a linha da table?

Segue XHTML

```
    <h:form id="form">          
        <f:metadata>    
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{cenarioBean.prepararListaFCQ}"/>    
        </f:metadata>

        <p:dataTable var="f" value="#{cenarioBean.auxFCQ}"
            paginator="false" rows="4" class="dataTable" id="dataTable" 
            emptyMessage="Nenhum Fluxo de Qualificacao Cadastrado">

            <p:column width="1">
                <p:rowToggler />
            </p:column>

            <p:columns value="#{cenarioBean.getColunas()}" var="c" headerText="#{c}" styleClass="column" width="#{c.startsWith('T') ? 200 : 60}">
                <h:outputText value="#{cenarioBean.getValorFCQ()}" />
            </p:columns>    

            <p:rowExpansion>
                Teste
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar o rendered pelo nome da coluna que você quer o Expand.

Exemplo:

```
<p:rowExpansion rendered="#{c.nomeColuna == 'Coluna A' or c.nomeColuna == 'Coluna B}">
     Teste 
</p:rowExpansion>
```

Acredito que esta condição resolva seu caso.

Answer (score 0):

A opção do amigo acima e boa também, caso fosse algum detalhamento eu usaria assim se a lista nao for vazia mostra.

```
<p:rowExpansion rendered="#{not empty lista.lstItems}">
    Teste 
</p:rowExpansio>
```